# How do I use SMOTE function in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I've recently started ML and I bumped into the SMOTE function which is meant to deal with the imbalance in my data. I ran `X_train.shape, y_train.shape` before sampling and got `((6010, 17)` and `(6010,))` respectively. After running the code below, I still get the same values when I run the shape methods on the new data. Was this not supposed to change? Or am I misunderstanding the concept? Another problem I have is that when I chance the sampling strategy, say to 0.6, I get the `error: 'negative dimensions not allowed.'` Help! Thanks.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

sm = SMOTE(random_state=45, sampling_strategy = 1.0)
X_train_sam, y_train_sam = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
```

This is what y_train looks like:

```
array([False,  True, False, ...,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: You mean you run `X_train_sam.shape` and you get the same result as `X_train.shape`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Can you try with `fit_resample` instead? It's not clear from the docs what is the purpose of the `fit_sample` you are currently using...

Comment: I've tried fit_resample, fit_sample and even sample. I'm really not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: Please show a sample of your `y_train` (not here, update your post)

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue using dummy data... please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)